# In ASP.NET MVC how can I use the Razor @Url.Content() helper from C# code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write a html helper extension that outputs an image tag.
I need to access (within C# code) something like Razor's @Url.Content() helper to get the proper URL for the current context.
How does one do this?

Comment: Why don't you write an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?

Comment: You need to be more specific than 'from code'. It's all code. Do you mean from a controller action?

Comment: Take a look at this article [http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/02/18/asp.net-mvc-tip-47-ndash-using-resolveurl-in-an-html.aspx](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/02/18/asp.net-mvc-tip-47-ndash-using-resolveurl-in-an-html.aspx) by [Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/default.aspx).

Answer (score 90):

Use the following to mimic Url.Content in code.

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/url/");
```

Comment: This is cool, Is there any scenario/edgecase where Url.Content() provides different result than this?

Comment: If your url has query string parameters, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute() will throw an error, Url.Content does not.

Answer (score 41):

You can create your own instance of `UrlHelper` by passing in the appropriate `ViewContext`.  For example, to do this from an image helper:

```
public static string CustomImage(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var Url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
}
```

At this point you can call `Url.Content()` or any other `UrlHelper` method.

Comment: In RC1 that should be "var url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);"

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

```
public static string MyHelper(this HtmlHelper h)
{
      string url = h.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

From a controller you can call:

`this.Url.Content("~/Somerelativepath?somethingelse=true");`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use this code to add `Url.Content` into your code:

```
var img_btn_edit = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/images/pencil.png");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get to the Request object and thus the URL like this:

```
string fullUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```