# In ASP.NET MVC, how do you retrieve the filename of the script being run?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request

I need to get the name of the script being executed on the master page to update the Last Write time.

I'm using this:

`System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath(Request.FilePath))`

which works for the default.aspx, but if its within a View I am unable to workout what the physical path to the file is to get the LastWriteTime.

Is there a solution to this? Surely I'm missing something incredibly easy here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I know about System.Web.Routing, the routing happens in IIS, making it impossible to get the true physical path of your View.
You can always try to use

```
this.Request.PhysicalPath
```

to get the physical path but it will return something like :

```
C:\Projects\MySolution\MyProject\ViewFolder\ViewAction
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937779/correct-way-to-reference-javascript-in-asp-net-mvc/938685#938685) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351937/in-asp-net-mvc-how-can-use-i-url-content-from-code), I wrote a html helper like so:

```
    public static string ScriptBlock(this HtmlHelper html, string path)
    {
        return string.Format("<script src=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\r\n", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path), DateLastWriteFile(html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(path)));
    }

    public static string CSSBlock(this HtmlHelper html, string path)
    {
        return string.Format("<link href=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"Stylesheet\" ></link>\r\n", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path), DateLastWriteFile(html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(path)));
    }

    public static string DateLastWriteFile(string path)
    {
        return "?Date=" + File.GetLastWriteTime(path).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
    }
```

Then, I simply call the method in my master or view pages, after including the proper namespace at the top of the view/master page obviously:

```
   <%= Html.CSSBlock("~/Content/Site.css") %>
```