# using jquery libraries in asp.net user controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm experiencing a strange issue. I'm using JQuery date-picker in my user control. When I try with google hosted libraries, things work nicely.

ie:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Next I downloaded the two libraries added them to my project(asp.net web site). When I reference them and try to run, it doesn't recognize jquery syntax (stops at jquery code and saying $ is not recognized). But intellisense is working.

this is my code:

```
<script src="../_Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../_Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>

<script type ="text/javascript">

 $(function () {
     $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
  });
 </script>


 <asp:TextBox runat ="server" ID ="TextBox1" Width ="80px"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

where is it going wrong? Some insight is really appreciated.

Comment: src="../_Scripts.  Is that the correct location when you are running your application?

Comment: yes thats what I get when I dragged and dropped on to page. I tried it with only _Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js but didn't work

Comment: Did you check the console in the browser's dev tools for errors?

Comment: `<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/_Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>`   Try that and do that to the other one.

Comment: @RickS I get "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined"

Comment: @user3241191 yes! your suggestion worked. You saved my day. Can you post it as answer so I can accept. It will help someone

Comment: I was actually able to help and provide an answer.  I think I need to quit for today while I'm ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/_Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Try that and do that to the other one.

Reference: [How to Properly Reference a JavaScript File in an ASP.NET Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509508/how-to-properly-reference-a-javascript-file-in-an-asp-net-project)