# how to create a asp.net mvc form helper that takes virtual directory into consideration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how to create a asp.net mvc form helper that takes virtual directory into consideration?

In testing our dev server has:

```
http://devserver1/some_virt_directory/
```

production is:

```
http://www.example.com
```

I need the form post url to reflect if we have a virtual directory or not, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [existing form helper methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx) already take into account this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName")) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **UrlHelper.Content**(..) method to resolve URLs taking into account what the real root is. The method will resolve the tilde ~ character. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351937/in-asp-net-mvc-how-can-use-i-url-content-from-code) for a related question on SO.