# show image from another server HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image

I have this image URL i got from database.

```
\\Imagepath\ImageFolder\image.png
```

but i need to put in a img tag in html to show the image in the page, i try to do this way

```
<img src='\\Imagepath\ImageFolder\image.png'/>
```

but the page adds the default url for localhost, ie.

```
http://localhost:1234/\\Imagepath\ImageFolder\image.png
```

I need your helpfor trying to get the image from that server URL.
I have a lot of images around 6,200 so is not an option to download, i'm show the images in a table.

> NOTE: i know the img tag not accept the URL like i have, but maybe you have an idea to do in ASP.NET, i apretiate your help.
>
> NOTE 2:i'm using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Add the attribute runat="server" to the image tag and set the image url from server side

Comment: @mbadeveloper: `runat="server"` is not applicable to MVC.

Comment: check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645382/mvc-helper-using-url-for-image-src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths starting with `\\` are [UNC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/62e862f4-2a51-452e-8eeb-dc4ff5ee33cc) paths, they are not URLs. In a browser, you have to use a URL to load an image.

The browser is assuming you've tried to specify a relative URL, and is attempting to add the current URL by default in order to fully qualify it and then make a request to it to get the image.

You need to map the path to a virtual directory in your webserver and then point the image's `src` property at the URL of that virtual directory.

Alternatively, if that's not a workable solution you could write an MVC action method which takes the name of the image file as a parameter and then loads the image from the UNC path in the background and returns the data in a binary response to the browser.

Comment: thanks to your question, now i undertand what is the problem with the URL i have, searching about i found this link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859535/html-image-source-from-unc-path ; i hope this help me to solve that.

Comment: @DavidMendezGuardado yes that's a good idea, although personally I would return the image as a binary response rather than having the overhead of converting to base64. But it's up to you.