# Create a root site enabled anchor tag link in an Html Extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 application.

I am adding static html files for help pages, located in a Help folder under the root project.

I have created an Html Helper extension to create the anchor tag.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TestHelpLink(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string helpTopic)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<a target='_blank' href='~/help/" + helpTopic + ".html'>");

    sb.Append("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'></i>");
    sb.Append("</a>");

    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

The problem occurs when deploying the application to IIS in the production environment.

The root url is being ignored even though I am using the ~ format which I thought would solve that specific issue.

If I copy the result string of the extension method and paste it directly into the HTML of a View, then both local and deployed versions work correctly as expected.

Is there something I should be doing differently in my extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining generated URL, I found the `href` part from anchor tag isn't converted to correct page URL like this:

```
<a target='_blank' href='~/help/[help topic].html'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'>Link Text</i></a>
```

From output string given above, we can conclude that `MvcHtmlString` doesn't automatically convert relative URL path with leading `~/` format, hence the relative URL part should converted with `UrlHelper.Content()` method which contains current `ViewContext.RequestContext` from `HtmlHelper` class (credits to @Curtis Buys):

```
public static MvcHtmlString TestHelpLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string helpTopic)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    // taken from /a/363994/6378815
    var url = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

    sb.Append("<a target='_blank' href='" + url.Content("~/help/" + helpTopic + ".html") + "'>");
    sb.Append("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'>Test Link</i>");
    sb.Append("</a>");

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

The modified method will produce this anchor tag (using browser inspector):

```
<!-- Correct output -->
<a target='_blank' href='/help/[help topic].html'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'>Link Text</i></a>
```

PS: The `TagHelper` class can be used to build anchor tag with same corrected output as above, with `MergeAttribute` method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TestHelpLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string helpTopic)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    // taken from /a/363994/6378815
    var url = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

    var builder = new TagBuilder("a");
    builder.MergeAttribute("target", "_blank");
    builder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Content("~/help/" + helpTopic + ".html"));

    sb.Append(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    sb.Append("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'>Link Text</i>");
    sb.Append(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

References:

[UrlHelper.Content Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) (MSDN)

[In ASP.NET MVC how can I use the Razor @Url.Content() helper from C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351937/in-asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-use-the-razor-url-content-helper-from-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.